# How to test difference from 50%

Tags: r, anova

I'm using R studio to analyse my data:
I have a dataset of zebrafish with independent variables: treatment and sex as in [this attached graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AwS5.png). I'm testing the percentage of 600s that the fish spend in the half of the tank containing conspecifics.

I have performed a 2-way anova to test the difference between the variables and the interaction, but I cant work out how to test each variable against the null hypothesis that the fish spend 50% of their time with the conspecifics.

I performed my anova using this script:

```
sp1 <- lm(percent ~ treatment + sex + treatment*sex, social.prefss)
anova(sp1)
```

I'm sorry if I've explained this poorly, I'm only an undergrad and havent got a great grasp of statistics!

EDIT:
I've just tried to do a one sample t-test by using this script:

```
per<-social.prefss$percent
treat<-social.prefss$treatment
sex<-social.prefss$sex
x<-social.prefss$percent
t.test(x,mu=50
```

and this is what came out:

> One Sample t-test
>
> data:  x
>
> t = 9.2808, df = 39, p-value = 2.028e-11
>
> alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 50
>
> 95 percent confidence interval:
>
> 65.36873 73.93460
>
> sample estimates:
>
> mean of x
>
> 69.65167

Comment: I've flagged this for migration to Stats because it doesn't appear to be about any specific programming language.

Comment: sorry, i forgot to say I'm using R

Comment: Please edit to add this tag. I'm still not sure this is a programming Q, possibly more just general stats. Did you have some problem that is specific to R?

Comment: I think its both really - I dont know whether its a particular statistical test that I'm looking for, or just a way to add specific parameters to the test I've done?

Comment: Certainly adding the `R` tag and an example of the code you've already tried will help - which I see you've just done. So, we can see your results. Do they differ from your expectations?

Comment: well the t-test shows what I'd expect, overall the data is all above 50% so it makes sense that this would be significant. But I'm not sure that for example, scheckstoff female would necessarily be significantly different from 50%. Would it make sense to create a new data set with just this category, and do a one sample t-test on that?

Comment: Sadly I've forgotten most of what I ever learned about stats... I think this is less specific to any particular language, and more about the general theory. So, I suspect you'd get a more useful response on the Stats subsite, but hey, I might be wrong.

Comment: ok thanks for your help, how can I move it to Stats subsite?

Comment: `?prop.test` or `?binom.test`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach makes a lot of sense and I think you are using the appropriate statistical tests. Really what you are doing is testing a few different research questions, which is why you need a few statistical tests. These are the questions I think you are trying to answer:

1) Does each group of fish spend more time with the conspecific than would be expected by chance? You could conduct a one sample t-test (as you have done). I would do a separate one sample t-test for each cell in your 2 by 2 (Female- Control, Male – Control, Female – Schreckstoff, Male - Schreckstoff). From your graph it looks like you would reject the null hypothesis in most of the cells, but maybe not for the Female – Schreckstoff cell.

2) Is there an interaction between sex and condition? Is there a main effect of sex? Is there a main effect of condition? You can answer these questions by examining the results of your ANOVA test.

Then you would be able to address how sex and condition effect time spent with conspecifics and for each group whether they spend more time than you would expect by chance.